# Spring cloud stream transform expression syntax

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am experimenting with Spring Cloud Stream using the local Spring Cloud Dataflow server and the shell. I've gotten simple examples like this

```
dataflow:>stream create --name test --definition "time --trigger.time-unit=SECONDS | log" --deploy
```

working correctly, in that I see a message in the log once per second.

```
2017-08-09 12:51:30,602  INFO -kafka-listener-1 log-sink:202 - 08/09/17 12:51:30
2017-08-09 12:51:31,603  INFO -kafka-listener-1 log-sink:202 - 08/09/17 12:51:31
2017-08-09 12:51:32,605  INFO -kafka-listener-1 log-sink:202 - 08/09/17 12:51:32
.... more log msgs ....
```

Now I'm trying to expand this example to insert a transform. Instead of the time, I want to see 'hello world' in the log once per second, and I can't figure out how to specify the expression properly.

I've tried this:

```
dataflow:>stream create --name test --definition "time --trigger.time-unit=SECONDS | transform --transformer.expression='hello world' | log" --deploy
```

and this (note addition of '#{}'):

```
dataflow:>stream create --name test --definition "time --trigger.time-unit=SECONDS | transform --transformer.expression=#{'hello world'} | log" --deploy
```

But I continue to get an error in the transform log:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' 
  to required type 'org.springframework.expression.Expression' for 
  property 'expression'; nested exception is 
  org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter 
  found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type 
  [org.springframework.expression.Expression]
```

I have read the [Spring Expression Language docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) (which I'm not finding helpful since the examples are all in terms of Java code). I've also looked at some of the Spring Cloud Stream [test code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/blob/master/processor/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-httpclient/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/httpclient/processor/HttpClientProcessorTests.java) for examples.

What am I missing?

Once I get 'hello world' working, I'd like to echo a property out of the local Dataflow Server's application.yml file too; suggestions welcome!

---

Update: I followed the [quick-start](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.3.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started) docs for the 1.3.0.M1 milestone. The apps are loaded with

```
dataflow:>app import --uri http://bit-ly/Bacon-RELEASE-stream-applications-kafka-10-maven
```

just as documented. (Note, replaced bit.ly with bit-ly for purposes of this post since StackOverflow doesn't like bit.ly URLs.) When I hit the bit.ly URL directly in my browser and download the file, I see this:

```
source.file=maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:file-source-kafka-10:1.2.0.RELEASE
source.file.metadata=maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:file-source-kafka-10:jar:metadata:1.2.0.RELEASE
source.ftp=maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:ftp-source-kafka-10:1.2.0.RELEASE
....
```

What URL should I use in order to download the 1.3.0.M1 apps? Is it a problem that the 1.2.0 apps don't appear to work with the 1.3.0.M1 server?

Comment: To insert a literal expression from the shell you need `\"'hello'\"` or `'''hello'''`.

Comment: @GaryRussell, that was it. I used the `'''hello'''` version and that works. I actually thought of and tried shell escaping but apparently didn't hit the right incantation. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it. For special chars like '?' do I just backslash them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation 'White space and quote rules'](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#shell-white-space).

To insert a literal expression from the shell you need \"'hello'\" or '''hello'''.

Comment: All the documentation I've read over the last day or so and I somehow managed to miss this section. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you use some old versions for SCDF and all those out-of-the-box apps.

All the apps has something like this in the `transform`:

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TransformProcessorProperties.class)
public class TransformProcessorConfiguration {
```

Where `@EnableBinding` comes from Spring Cloud Stream with the:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ BindingServiceConfiguration.class, BindingBeansRegistrar.class, BinderFactoryConfiguration.class,
        SpelExpressionConverterConfiguration.class })
@EnableIntegration
public @interface EnableBinding {
```

Pay attention to the `SpelExpressionConverterConfiguration`. Exactly this one is responsible for converting strings to the `Expression` properties.

So, be sure that you use the latest `Bacon` SCSt Apps: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Bacon.RELEASE/reference/html/

Comment: To insert a literal expression from the shell you need `\"'hello'\"` or `'''hello'''`.